# jquery get data on keyup not working

Tags: php, jquery

I want to show data from database on key change, they will input place name, and it will check database with getPlaces.php and output on showlist div.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){

    $('form')[0].reset();
    $("form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    //$("#place").focus();

    $('#place').on('keyup', function(e){
        var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
        var keyword = $('#place').val();
        if (keyword.lengtd>= min_length) {

            $.post("getPlaces.php", $('form').serialize(),  function(response) {
                $('#showlist').html(response);
                $('#showlist').show();
            });

        }
    });

});//]]>

</script>

</head>
<body id="up">

    <div id="form"><form><input type="text" id="place" name="place" placeholder="write area name .."  /></form></div>
    <div id="showlist">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

php file is working perfectly. but i am not getting any content!

Comment: It looks like keyword.length is misspelled

Comment: @tabz100 thanks. working excellent now. couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `keyword.lengtd`. It should be `keyword.length`.

Answer (score 0):

**use this script code**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){

    $('form')[0].reset();
    $("form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    //$("#place").focus();

    $('#place').on('keyup', function(e){
        var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
        var keyword = $('#place').val();
        if (keyword.length >= min_length) {

            $.post("getPlaces.php", $('form').serialize(),  function(response) {
                $('#showlist').html(response);
                $('#showlist').show();
            });

        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Add little description to your code. That will make your answer more suitable and acceptable